# key value pair implementation in java?

Tags: java

Is there something like a `KeyValuePair` in Java?

I have a Very long list of elements of the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    int id;
    Set<String> items;
}
```

which is stored here:

```
LinkedList<Foo> myList;
```

each time I search for a item, I iterate over the list and search for the Item, but this takes to much time.
I want to do something like this:

```
myList.get(123) => items of the Foo with id = 123
```

Comment: you could use a `Map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Map` in Java for that purpose. It will allow key, value pairs.

```
Map<Integer,Set<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,Set<String>>();
```

Adding item to map

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
      set.add("ABC");
      set.add("DEF");
      map.put(123,set);
```

Getting item from map

```
  map .get(123)  will give  Set<String>  associated  with id  123
```

Comment: @gurehbgui did you understand now

Comment: but when I make a additional put, I still have 1 item in the Map and not 2

Answer (score 4):

Try some impelementation of `java.util.Map`.

More info: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the `MultiMap<Integer,String>` is suitable in your case.

- [Guava MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
- [Apache commons MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

you would need a so called MultiMap, java dont has that by default, but you always can use a Map for that purpose.

Try using a `HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>`

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.*;

class temp{

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1,"anand");
    map.put(2,"bindu");
    map.put(3,"cirish");
    System.out.println(1+" = "+map.get(1));             
    System.out.println(2+" = "+map.get(2));
    System.out.println(3+" = "+map.get(3));

    Map<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    map1.put("anand",1);
    map1.put("bindu",2);
    map1.put("cirish",3);
    System.out.println("anand = "+map1.get("anand"));               
    System.out.println("bindu = "+map1.get("bindu"));

    if(map1.get("cirish") != null){
        System.out.println("cirish = "+map1.get("cirish"));
    }

    if(map1.get("dinesh") != null){
        System.out.println("cirish = "+map1.get("dinesh"));
    }
}
```

}